# I want to display registered person details like (first name , email , phone number) in profile.html template - django

Tags: python, html, django

**models.py**

```
class Register(models.Model):
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    companyname=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I want to display these details in `profile.html` template. How can I modify **views.py**

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
   return render(request, 'web/profile.html')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with class based view if that works:

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Register

class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Register
    context_object_name = 'profile_data_from_view' # this is the name you use in the template
    template_name = 'web/profile.html'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('profile/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

profile.html:

```
...your html...
<p>Fullname: {{ profile_data_from_view.fullname }}</p>
<p>Companyname: {{ profile_data_from_view.companyname }}</p>
<p>Email: {{ profile_data_from_view.email }}</p>
<p>Contactno: {{ profile_data_from_view.contactno }}</p>
...rest of your html...
```

Comment: Showing Error AttributeError at /web/profile/
Generic detail view ProfileDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: My bad, you need to add the `get_absolute_url` method to your model.
```

Comment: My bad, you need to add the `get_absolute_url` method to your model.
```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[str(self.id)])
```
The error you are getting says that django does not know which profile it needs to display

Try this after you made the abs_url:
<p>Fullname: <a href="{{ profile_data_from_view.get_absolute_url }}">{{ profile_data_from_view.fullname }}</a></p>

This should make a link to the profile page

Also, this is a good tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views#book_detail_page

Comment: but it was showing some error called page not found. but the path i had given are correct.